# O HTML5 AudioElement não reproduz audio em dispositivos IOS 13

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, html5-audio

Sou desenvolvedor web de uma emissora de rádio. Desde o lançamento do IOS 13, recebemos várias reclamações de usuários de que nossas transmissões ao vivo de áudio não podem mais ser reproduzidas em dispositivos IOS (iPhone). Em outros dispositivos reproduzem os fluxos sem nenhum problema.

Obs.: Foram feito testes num **iPhone de versão 13.3.1** e ao apertar o botão de play o áudio **não foi reproduzido**. Porém em um **iPad Mini de versão 9.3.5 foi reproduzido**

Link de acesso ao site: https://vipfm.net

Para testar, acesse o link acima e aperte o play (deve reproduzir o áudio)

Parte do código onde é implementado o Player:

```
import { Flex, Box } from "../../styles/grid";
import {
  ContainerNew,
  MusicContainerBusiness,
  NameMusic,
  InfoMusic,
  PlayButton,
  Volume,
  Sound
} from "./style";
import { FaPlay, FaPause } from "react-icons/fa";

const Player = ({ theme, width, radio, host, isNewTemplate, isMobile }) => {
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(true);
  const [program, setProgram] = useState(false);
  const [music, setMusic] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(
        `https://music.suaradionanet.net/api/music?slug=${radio.slug}`,
        {
          headers: {
            "x-api-key": "Gr(23ksASI!k)d9OaPD6"
          }
        }
      );
      const res = await result.json();
      setProgram(res[1] ? res[0] : false);
      setMusic(res[1] ? res[1] : res[0]);
    };
    fetchData();
    setInterval(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, 100000);
  }, []);
  const handlePlayer = () => {
    const sound = document.getElementById("sound");
    setPaused(!paused);

    if (paused) sound.play();
    else sound.pause();
  };

  const handleVolume = e => {
    document.getElementById("sound").volume = e;
  };

  return (
    <ContainerNew
      width={width}
      isHeaderPlayer={radio.sitebasic.header_player}
      isNewTemplate={isNewTemplate}
      flexDirection="column"
    >
      <Flex mb={12}>
        <PlayButton onClick={handlePlayer} isBusinessCard>
          {paused ? (
            <FaPlay color={`rgb(${theme.primaryColor})`} />
          ) : (
            <FaPause color={`rgb(${theme.primaryColor})`} />
          )}
        </PlayButton>
        <Volume>
          <input
            className="volume"
            type="range"
            onChange={e => handleVolume(e.target.value)}
            min="0"
            max="1"
            step="0.1"
            defaultValue="1"
          />
        </Volume>
        {!isMobile || isMobile === "Android" ? (
          <Sound preload="none" id="sound">
            <source src={radio.streaming_link} type="audio/aac" />
            <source src={radio.streaming_link} type="audio/mpeg" />
            <source src={radio.streaming_link} type="audio/wav" />
            <source src={radio.streaming_link} type="audio/mp4" />
            <source src={radio.streaming_link} type="audio/aacp" />
            <source src={radio.streaming_link} type="audio/ogg" />
            <source src={radio.streaming_link} type="audio/webm" />
            <source src={radio.streaming_link} type="audio/flac" />
          </Sound>
        ) : (
          isMobile === "iOS" && (
            <Sound preload="none" id="sound">
              <source src={`${radio.streaming_link}.m3u`} type="audio/aac" />
              <source src={`${radio.streaming_link}.m3u`} type="audio/mpeg" />
              <source src={`${radio.streaming_link}.m3u`} type="audio/wav" />
              <source src={`${radio.streaming_link}.m3u`} type="audio/mp4" />
              <source src={`${radio.streaming_link}.m3u`} type="audio/aacp" />
              <source src={`${radio.streaming_link}.m3u`} type="audio/ogg" />
              <source src={`${radio.streaming_link}.m3u`} type="audio/webm" />
              <source src={`${radio.streaming_link}.m3u`} type="audio/flac" />
            </Sound>
          )
        )}
      </Flex>
      <MusicContainerBusiness>
        {music && <NameMusic>{music.music}</NameMusic>}
        {program && (
          <InfoMusic>
            {program.program} - {program.time_begin} / 23:00h
          </InfoMusic>
        )}
      </MusicContainerBusiness>
    </ContainerNew>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

Alguém tem uma idéia de por que nossos fluxos não funcionam mais e pode nos dar conselhos sobre o que podemos fazer para fazê-los funcionar novamente?

Comment: Consegue depurar no Safari? Se estiver ligado o celular com o cabo no seu Mac é possivel depurar os erros no console do Safari, consegue pegar esse log para analisarmos?

Comment: Infelizmente, não consigo. Todos os testes que foram feitos, eram em dispositivos de terceiros. Por tanto, eles não saberiam como fazer isso e me passar as informações, mas mesmo assim, valeu pela ajuda!